# Tips for language design: still on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Currently, we have two open questions tagged [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) [language-design](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-design):

- [Tips for storage in a golfing language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118111/tips-for-storage-in-a-golfing-language)
- [Tips for Creating/Maintaining a Golfing Language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/198446/tips-for-creating-maintaining-a-golfing-language)

Now that there is a StackExchange site for [Programming Language Design and Implementation](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/) (in private beta as of this writing), **do we still want to allow language design questions here on CGCC, or should they be asked at PLDI?**

The same question was [previously asked four years ago](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17366/16766), but it didn't get a straight answer, and that was before PLDI existed.

This issue is also being discussed from the opposite direction on PLDI meta: [When should a golfing language question be posted here vs. on CGCC?](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80/when-should-a-golfing-language-question-be-posted-here-vs-on-cgcc) The [current top-voted answer](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/81/27) suggests the following "rough heuristic":

> Thus, if your question would benefit from detailed discussion of golfiness, it may be better on CGCC (but is perfectly fine here!), and if it would benefit more from advice from langdevs from a variety of backgrounds, it may be better here (but is perfectly fine on CGCC).

So it looks like such questions will be on-topic at PLDI regardless. Do we want them *also* to be on-topic here?

(This question does not apply to actual challenges tagged [language-design](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-design), which are definitely on-topic.)

Comment: Reading the meta post in PLDI properly does suggest they would be allowed there but the choice would be up to OP

Comment: @mousetail Good point, I edited my summary to clarify that.

Comment: For my two cents, I don't think the existence or non-existence of other sites should really matter for this.